# How can I remove the "<pre>" tags in Hubot httpd script?

Tags: node.js, hubot

By default, hubot httpd.coffee script puts a pre tag in the output.
Is there anyway to remove it?
I'm trying to make hubot generate some basic html pages.

```
spawn = require('child_process').spawn
Fs   = require 'fs'

module.exports = (robot) ->
    robot.router.get "/", (req, res) ->
        res.end "Hi, i am a <b>robot</b>!"
```

the output, in the web page, must be like:
`Hi, i am a robot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hubot's HTTP server is based on ExpressJS, so I suggest reading this guide: http://expressjs.com/guide.html

You can try using `res.send`:

```
spawn = require('child_process').spawn
Fs   = require 'fs'

module.exports = (robot) ->
    robot.router.get "/", (req, res) ->
        res.send "Hi, i am a <b>robot</b>!"
        res.end()
```